# Dynamic database connection string, User id should be taken from (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

```
public appEntities() : base("name=appEntities") 
{     
}
```

I need to create connection string dynamically, my database user id and session user id will be the same. how can I achieve this?

Comment: What's the problem here, provide the complete details. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i cant see anything there.

Answer (score 0):

Generate the dynamic connection string before any request start.

Application_BeginRequest

Comment: pls give an example

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/dynamically-generating-connection-string-for-entity-framework